# google-oauth-java-client - Force access token default lifetime

Tags: java, google-api, google-oauth

I'm wondering if it's possible to change the default lifetime (3600) ?

In fact, i'm trying to solve an issue and i want to check if the issue is due to an expired access token..

Else, is it possible to force the access token used by a credential ?

Let me know if it's not clear.
Regards,

Sebastien

Answer (score 1):

You cannot change the lifetime of an access token. You could, however, get a refresh token that can be used to get fresh access tokens (see [Google OAuth2 docs](https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2WebServer)).

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.
I know it, in fact i just want to raise an error when the access token is expired and for now, the main problem is i've to wait one hour to test it...

But if it's sure that not possible de force it, i can close my question.

Regards,